# How to delete the user_data in a custom TreeModel in in gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtk3

I create user_data something like this:

```
bool
MyTreeModel::iter_nth_root_child_vfunc (int index, iterator & iter) const
{
   iter .gobj () -> user_data = new UserData (...);
   return true;
}
```

I can create the user data, but is there a way to get notified when the iterator is destroyed, so I can delete my user data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; `user_data` is a non-owning pointer.  You should parallel the tree with a node-based container (e.g. `std::map`) and store your `UserData` objects in that, with the `user_data` pointer pointing into the container.